# Request Promise unhandled reject

Tags: node.js, request

Basically I have to do a POST request an try to save this data on an API after I get the return of this POST and save this information on a database.

So, I did a call to a promise `(saveProcessedData or saveErrorData)` inside another promise, works as expected although is trowing out a warning:

> Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 400

```
const sendData = async(data, item) => {

    let payload = [],
        dataProcessed = [];

    let options = { 
        method: data.endpoint.method,
        url: api._url + data.endpoint.url,
        headers: 
        { 
            'Postman-Token': api._postmanToken,
            'cache-control': api._cache,
            'x-ccasset-language': 'en',
            Authorization: data.token
        },
        body: item,
        json: true 
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        api._request(options, async (error, response, body) => {
            if(!response.body.errorCode && response.statusCode === 200) {
                payload = {
                    body: response.body,
                    type: data.req.body.type
                }
                dataProcessed = await db.saveProcessedData(payload);
            } else {
                payload = {
                    body: item,
                    type: data.req.body.type,
                    description: response.body.message
                }
                dataProcessed = await db.saveErrorData(payload);
            }

            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }

            resolve(dataProcessed);
        });
    });
}
```

How Can I catch this error?

Comment: Are you using `request` or `request-promise`?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande request-promise

Comment: Show what `api` is, specially `api._request` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just formatting

```
const sendData = async (data, item) => {

    const options = {
        method: data.endpoint.method,
        url: api._url + data.endpoint.url,
        headers: {
            'Postman-Token': api._postmanToken,
            'cache-control': api._cache,
            'x-ccasset-language': 'en',
            Authorization: data.token
        },
        body: item,
        json: true
    };

    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                api._request(options, (error, response) => {
                    if (!response.body.errorCode && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        return resolve(
                            {
                                body: response.body,
                                type: data.req.body.type
                            }
                        );

                    }
                    return reject({
                        body: item,
                        type: data.req.body.type,
                        description: error || response.body.message
                    });
                })
            }))
        .then(payload => db.saveProcessedData(payload))
        .catch(payload => db.saveErrorData(payload))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you don't mix callbacks & promises the way you're doing it. You're getting that error because you're not handling the errors correctly inside `api._request` callback.

Wrap your code inside the callback in a `try/catch`, because that's how you handle exceptions in `async` functions.

```
new Promise(async resolve => {
    await Promise.reject() // Unhandled Promise Rejection
}).catch(console.error) // not catched
```

Should be:

```
new Promise(async resolve => {
    try {
       await Promise.reject()
       resolve();
    } catch(e) {
       reject(e)
    }

}).catch(console.error) // catched
```

In any case, since you're wrapping `api._request` in a Promise, it would be better to do:

```
const sendData = async(data, item) => {

    // ...

    const { error, response, body } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        api._request(options, (error, response, body) => resolve({ error, response, body }))
    })

    if(!response.body.errorCode && response.statusCode === 200) {
        payload = {
            body: response.body,
            type: data.req.body.type
        }
        dataProcessed = await db.saveProcessedData(payload);
    } else {
        payload = {
            body: item,
            type: data.req.body.type,
            description: response.body.message
        }
        dataProcessed = await db.saveErrorData(payload);
    }

    return dataProcessed;
}
```

And attach a `.catch` handler to `.sendData`

Aside from that in your code, if `error` is truthy, you're rejecting and then `resolving`, nothing wrong will happen in that case, but it's better to use `return reject()`. A Promise, can't be rejected & resolved.

```
if (error) {
   return reject(error)
}

resolve(dataProcessed);
```

---

If you're using `request`, you can use `request-promise` or `request-promise-native` which are Promise wrappers around `request` package.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `sendData()` you can use `Promise.prototype.catch()` to catch exceptions that occurred in your promise, including any `reject()`:

```
sendData(myData, myItem)
    .then(result => {
        //do stuff with result 
    }
    .catch(error => {
        //handle error
    };
```

Comment: You should use a lower case on promise: `promise.cache()` or even `yourPromise.catch()`, it looks like a static method on the constructor.

Comment: In the description of my answer I used Promise with a capital P because I am referring to the prototype method of Promise.

Comment: That's not the whole issue though, that `.catch` won't solve the issue. Check my answer.

Comment: Sure it will. This .catch() will catch any exception thrown in the sendData promise. I just tried it out myself.

Comment: No, if `db.` method fails, it won't catch it. Since it's happening in a new Promise inside the Promise wrapp.

Comment: Oh yes, any inner promises need to be caught the same way using .catch(). Your answer is definitely more complete than mine, as mine just covers the concept. I targeted sendData specifically since the exception he's getting is from the request promise (StatusCodeError: 400). You are right though the db.promise also needs to be handled in the event the database promise throws an exception.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez so it should be `Promise.prototype.catch`, `Promise.catch` is not the same thing